# Force Http Get to accept requests either with or without parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, webapi

Consider the Controller :

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    // https://localhost:44344/api/employee/:profession
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/employee/{profession}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(String profession)
    {            

        try
        {
            var someBigList = ...
            /// ... do some stuff
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, someBigList );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // error
        }
    }


}
```

The controller accepts requests in the form :

```
https://localhost:44344/api/employee/:profession
```

However when I try

```
https://localhost:44344/api/employee
```

It doesn't.

How can we fix the GET request to accept both ?

Comment: public HttpResponseMessage Get(String profession = null)

Comment: @SirRufo: Doesn't work

Comment: Reminder to myself: Do not comment/answer before first coffee of the day ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark optional parameters in the route with `?` so this would be `[Route("api/employee/{profession?}")]`

Or if you want it to have a default value in case no value is given then use `[Route("api/employee/{profession=value}")]`

See more from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thanks , however I got : 

`{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44344/api/employee'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'employee' that matches the request."
}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow both the URL then you will have to add one more Route. This will simply route your request to action method. 
Now since you need one parameter then it should be passed in request parameter which will come as part of query string.

New Route should look like below.

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    // https://localhost:44344/api/employee/:profession
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/employee")]
    [Route("api/employee/{profession}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(String profession)
    {            

        try
        {
            var someBigList = ...
            /// ... do some stuff
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, someBigList );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // error
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience if it's not a required parameter then I take the value from query, not from route.
So you can use `[FromQuery] string profession` and the usage is as following: https://localhost:44344/api/employee?profession=developer

Comment: There is no requirement to do it this way, even though it is possible. If you use “should” then please do provide information based on what it should be done like this.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for pointing this out! To be honest that's what was taught to us during CS studies and I took it for granted, and that's how I design APIs, but after a short lookup for this I do not find any standards for REST. Sorry for misleading answer, I'll edit it soon!